# How to not show the button if the user looks his/her own profile in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

All users have their own profiles. When you check other user's profile there is a button send a message. The problem is that button appears in your own profile too when you check your profile. How can I hide that button when I look at my own profile?

Here is the code:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.user = this.tokenService.GetPayload();
   this.socket.emit('online', { room: 'global', user: this.user.username });
   this.socket.on('refreshPage', () => {
   this.GetUserData(this.name);
});
```

According to the above code, it also shows online status for each user so I need to add something without touching above lines.

Here is the HTML part:

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-6">
  <a href="#" class="btn button-image closeButton btn-message float-right">Message</a>
</div>
```

I think there should be added ngIf in above div. But how can this issue be solved?

Comment: you must be storing username somewhere in localstorage may be? that which user is logged in, right?

Comment: Compare your `ID` with the `ID` of opened user, if `ID` matches dont show button otherwise make it visible

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the current username save it to the typescript something like

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.ownUsername = localStorage.getItem('ownUsername');
   this.user = this.tokenService.GetPayload();
   this.socket.emit('online', { room: 'global', user: this.user.username });
   this.socket.on('refreshPage', () => {
      this.GetUserData(this.name);
   });
}
```

The html should look something like this:

```
<div *ngIf="user.username !== ownUsername" class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-6">
  <a href="#" class="btn button-image closeButton btn-message float-right">Message</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you must be storing `username` somewhere in localstorage may be? that which user is logged in.

```
isMessageButtonShown() {
  const currentUser = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
  if (this.user.username === currentUser) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-6">
  <a href="#" *ngIf='isMessageButtonShown()' class="btn button-image closeButton btn-message float-right">Message</a>
</div>
```

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: The button is not disappearing.

Comment: have you changed the variables as per your decleration, or just copied and paste in the code?

Comment: Just copied.  Should I change only this part? localStorage.getItem('currentUser'); with localStorage.getItem('user'); ?

Comment: I've checked in Chrome's local storage there were empty. The project is based on JWT. Is there another way to fix this?

Comment: Brother, you must be stored somewhere that which user is logged in, so use that to check with loop

Answer (score 0):

You should use `*ngIF` [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

And have a boolean to know if it's the user's profile or not.

Let's say this boolean is called `isItMe`, that is set to false if it's not the currant user (set this boolean in your component initialization).

Then in your template you'll do it like this:

```
<div *ngIf="!isItMe" class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-6">
  <a href="#" class="btn button-image closeButton btn-message float-right">Message</a>
</div>
```